# Search Server 2010 Express - which service pack do I need?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

I have Microsoft Search Server 2010 Express - 14.0.4763.1000 installed and want to upgrade it at least to Service Pack 1.
There apears to be a service pack for SharePoint Foundation 2010 and one for Microsoft Search Server 2010 however I cannot find one specific to Search Server 2010 Express.

An which cumulative updates to I have to install exactly after SP1 to bring it up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Server Express is updated just like the full Search Server product.  You can find the SP1 listings here for all office server products:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2510766

CU should only be applied when they fix a "specific" problem you are having, and have been tested in your environment. It is not uncommon for a SharePoint CU to contain regressions, that is they tend to break something, even while fixing something else.

Todd Klindt has a pretty good list of build numbers and regressions associated with CU's here:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

Comment: Thank you very much. So is it correct that I only need to install Search Server SP1 and not the  SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1 as well?

Comment: You should apply foundation SP1 first, then Server SP1.  Also review the Known issues paper on SP1 which details other requirements after installation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2532126